# jQuery inside of setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So first some background. This code is to be used as a bookmarklet and I've done testing with it as a bookmarklet and as code pasted into the javascript console in Chrome. Either way I'm getting the same error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Now before anyone tells me that I don't have jQuery embedded anywhere in my code, this is to be used on a website that has jQuery, and when I paste the exact same code in just not inside of a setInterval() it works fine, so here's my very simple code.

```
javascript:window.setInterval(function() { $("#fbutton").click() }, 5000);
```

Comment: Well if you get the error, than jQuery is not $. And in the console of chrome $ is not jQuery! SO no, you do not have jQuery on the page. $ is a shortcut for document.querySelector in Chrome.

Comment: is this code being called before the window is loaded or outside of the on document load function normally used to run jquery functions? If the DOM isn't loaded then the code won't run.

Comment: But just $("#fbutton").click() works fine when it's not in a window.setInterval

Comment: This code is being loaded after the page loads

Comment: @NexusDesigns it is a shortcut for document.querySelector in the console...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#selector You do not have jQuery on the page.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, changed $ to that and it fixed it! I do have jQuery on the page, trust me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Chrome in the developer tools, $ is a shortcut for `document.querySelector`. So that is why it is valid in the console.

What you are running is actually

```
document.querySelector("#fbutton").click();
```

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#selector